# How to construct the routerLink to link correctly to the auxiliary route?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I got these routes:

```
{
  path: 'models',
  loadChildren: '../pages/+models-models/models-models.module#ModelsModelsModule',
  outlet: 'models'
},
{
  path: 'models/:id',
  loadChildren: '../pages/+model/model.module#ModelModule',
  outlet: 'models'
}
```

Which becomes: `/admin/dashboard/models/(models:models)` and `/admin/dashboard/models/(models:models/5)` respectively.

The `<router-outlet name="models"></router-outlet>` is inside a `ModelsComponent` which is at `/admin/dashboard/models`.

Now what I don't understand is how to construct a `routerLink` to link to link to these 2 routes, every time I try with something like:

```
[routerLink]="['models', {models: 'models'}]"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="{'models': {outlet: {models: 'models'}}}"
```

or

```
[routerLink]="{'models': {outlet: {models: 'models/id'}}}"
```

It just throws an error. I can't make any sense out of the sources I've found on this, since most of them don't even seem up to date with the latest releases.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use the same name for the path and the auxiliary outlet. In your case both are called models, which is confusing.

There is a property `primary` that defines the primary outlet.

See how I did it here: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/chapter3/router_samples/app/main-aux.ts

The Home component is shown in the primary outlet, and the Chat is shown in the outlet named aux.

Comment: `[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'models': 'models/' + model.id}}]` why does that throw error but manually going to `/admin/dashboard/models/(models:models/5)` works?

Comment: The URL segment that you're referring to is built by the Router by parsing the expression in your  routerLink directive.  This means that your expression in routerLink is not correct and doesn't generate the URL segment that enter manually.